# ormlite JdbcPooledConnectionSource correct usage

Tags: java, sqlite, ormlite

We are developing a new desktop application in JavaFx wherein for offline storage we are using SQLite and for orm we are using ormlite.

I want to implement DB connection pooling wherein a fixed number of connections should be set at the start and should be used, released and reused as required. Also, it would be good if we can make use of "readonly" and "writeonly" connections appropriately to maximize performance.

This is what we have written so far.

```
public class DAO {
    private static JdbcPooledConnectionSource connectionSource;

    private static DAO instance = null;

    private DAO() throws SQLException {
        try {
            final File path = SystemUtils.getDatabaseFile();
            final String DATABASE_URL = Constants.DATABASE_URL + path.getAbsolutePath();

            Class.forName(Constants.DATABASE_DRIVER);

            connectionSource = new JdbcPooledConnectionSource(DATABASE_URL);
            //connectionSource.setMaxConnectionAgeMillis(5 * 60 * 1000);
            connectionSource.setCheckConnectionsEveryMillis(5000);
            connectionSource.setMaxConnectionsFree(5);
            connectionSource.initialize();
            init();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    private void init() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, Customer.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, Address.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, Location.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, City.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, Area.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, Category.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, Product.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, AddonCategory.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, ProductAddon.class);

    }

    public synchronized <D extends Dao<T, ?>, T> D getDao(Class<T> cls) throws SQLException {
        Dao<T, ?> dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, cls);
        D daoImpl = (D) dao;

        return daoImpl;
    }

    public synchronized static DAO getInstance() throws SQLException {
        if (instance == null) instance = new DAO();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The problem here is everytime we are creating table (TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists) the pooled connection source is making a new connection and not reusing the one earlier used/created.

Not finding enough code examples on Internet on how to correctly use JdbcPooledConnectionSource.

Comment: So there are a lot of unit tests around the pooled connection source and re-use of connections.  Can you add more information about why you think it is the case?  https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/jdbc/JdbcPooledConnectionSourceTest.java

Comment: Also, depending on the database engine for SQLite you are using, a pooled connection source isn't going to help you because SQLite is usually embedded.  The pooled connection source really only helps with remote databases.

Comment: Thanks Gray! We are developing a desktop application (JavaFx) wherein the database is not embedded but is separate (SQLite file). I wanted to have an example DAO design pattern using pooled connection in ormlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JdbcPooledConnectionSource correct usage

Which SQLite driver are you using? The Xerial driver has the Sqlite code actually compiled into the Jar. This means that you really aren't "connecting" to another database just making calls to the database directly even though it is fronted by a JDBC interface.

This means that you really don't need a `JdbcPooledConnectionSource`.  The pooled connections really only help when you are making connections over the network to a database server.  If you look at your application, you should see file-descriptors (in /prod/#/fd if in Linux) which show open FDs to the database but not to sockets.

> The problem here is everytime we are creating table (TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists) the pooled connection source is making a new connection and not reusing the one earlier used/created.

Hrm.  I have some good coverage in unit tests around the pooled connection source.  I'm surprised to hear that it isn't reusing connections.  Can you get me a unit test to demonstrate it?

Comment: Thanks Gray! In case we don't use JdbcPooledConnectionSource, then how should we make sure that DB file is not locked while performing write operations. Are there any built-in functionality or we need to manage it on our own using locks or any other synchronization technique.

Comment: I don't understand the question @Rahul.B.  Sqlite handles the underlying locking.  I'm not sure if it gives you primitives to see if it is locked already.

Comment: See this link @Rahul.B.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822778/sqlite-connection-pool-in-java-locked-database

Comment: Thanks Gray for helping me out!